# Pointers against cheat

Tags: c++, class

How can i protect my **molecule class** variables values such as **bond length** and **inversion probability of NH3** from people like cheat-engine users (without slowing much)?

Does this protect from outer-effects?

```
class molecule
{
public:
    molecule()
    {
    ...
    }
protected:
    int *bond_length;
    int *probability;
}
```

Is this safer?

```
class molecule
{
...
private:
    int *bond_length;
    int *probability;
}
```

If all above are vulnerable against cheat-engine-like softwares, then can below be logical?

```
class molecule
{
public:
    molecule(){... ... ...}
...
...
    //still public
    int *bond_length_fake;
    int *bond_length;
    int *prob_fake;
    int *prob;
}
...
//somewhere in the program
void thread_real_to_fake(void * molecule_parameters)
{
    int bond_length_backup;
    molecule * param=(molecule *)molecule_parameters;
    while(working)
    {
        if((param->bond_length_fake)!=(param->bond_length))
        {
            param->bond_length_fake=param->bond_length;
        }
    }
    _endthread();

}
```

Okay, this protects the fake by making it equal to real one always. But how to protect real one? Can I use random-pointer to get the real value? If yes, how can I?

Comment: "Cheat engines" is kinda broad.. what kind of an attack are you facing ?

Comment: No attack yet. Just preparing against. Just like game-hack.

Comment: achieve computing on client computer with safety(edit:security)

Comment: It seems you are confusing the concept of "safety" and "security", and trying to map "c++ protection" (that is for safety: to protect against programming MISTAKES) to security (to protect against INTENTIONALLY MALICIOUS act) purposes.

Comment: Ok, i mean security against intentionally and malicious act.

Comment: So, FORGOT public, private and protected. They are not for security.

Comment: what about the last thing i mentioned with a thread?

Comment: Why do you suppose your chemistry program will be a target for hacking?

Comment: Because it will be a part of a game. Games are always hacked. :(

Comment: You might want to take a look at how BOINC projects do it. They need to run programs on unknown computers and rely on the result. It is inherently unsafe, so to make it usable they run the same data on many unrelated clients and compare the results. The moral being - if they cannot do it securely, it is a real problem :) All the anti-cheat game software solutions basically do some combination of obscurity tricks and heuristics to detect hacking attempts. But IMHO this can never be 100% reliable.

Comment: :( then this program will be less than **approximation**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You cannot protect your computer against running software. If someone is in control of the machine, they can manipulate it at will, and this includes modifying the state of a running program.

The safest thing you could do is run the program on a separate, inaccessible server and forward the I/O through the network (e.g. to a browser window).

*Edit:* As an alternative, you could run the engine part of your program as a service that runs as a separate user. This provides a certain amount of protection. The engine would have to check that the submitted user input (e.g. key strokes) come in at a reasonable rate. This allows you to enforce rules to a certain degree, but doesn't prevent for example the user from seeing through walls by manipulating the graphics rendering in the client.

Comment: You saying if i am using java then i need to compute things in a server rather than client computer (java servlet vs java applet).

Comment: @tuğrulbüyükışık: I'm saying that the only true way to protect your program against manipulation is to not permit any access to the machine on which it runs... this is just an abstract principle.

Comment: what privilage level does a person need to get a variable from another software running?

Comment: @tuğrulbüyükışık: Usually, a user can access memory from all processes that run under her own ownership, which is generally enough to do anything. You *might* be able to write your software as a service that runs as a different user and communicates through an interface, I suppose...

Comment: @tuğrulbüyükışık: it depends on the operating system.
But if you don't "own" yourself that computer someone else will, and have the privilege to change the privileges as well.